# Angular 2 http stub

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular2-services

Angular Experts,

I'm unit testing my application and I'm experimenting a little.

Specifically I'd like to unit test the Components with the real Services by just mocking the Http object. Right now I'm trying to stub the object by myself so I made the **StubHttp** class below.

Angular 2: verson 2.4.7 + Karma, Jasmine.

this is its simplified version:

```
let mockTest = '{"name":'John', // ...};

export class StubHttp {
  public post(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs) 
            :Observable<Response> {
    let response = new ResponseOptions({body: JSON.stringify(mockTest)});
    return Observable.of(new Response(response));
  }
}
```

If I put a log in my controller:

```
this.UsersService.getAll().subscribe(( data: any ) => {
   console.log('data = ', data);
});
```

and the service:

```
getAll( event: LazyLoadEvent) {
    return this.http.post( this.url + this.params, JSON.stringify( this.body ),new RequestOptions({headers: this.header}) )
        .map( response => response.json() )
        .catch( this.handleError );
}
```

this is the output:

```
LOG: 'data = ', Promise{}
```

where is the mistake?

Comment: In your Stub implementation I see only post, yet in the example you showed for your controller you call a method named getAll(). Does getAll() do an HTTP POST or a GET?

Comment: sorry! post updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by using XHRBackend and mockBackend instead of my Http Stub.

```
  it('Should show a list of 10 feed',
    inject([XHRBackend], (mockBackend) => {

      mockBackend.connections.subscribe((connection) => {
        connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({
          body: {id: 55}
        })));
      });

      // ... 
    }));
```

https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/11/28/testing-services-with-http-in-angular-2.html